# The procedure entry point CreateAppContainerProfile could not be located in the dynamic link library USERENV.dll

Tags: clion, entry-point

Clion doesn't open and it gives me "The procedure entry point CreateAppContainerProfile could not be located in the dynamic link library USERENV.dll" I have tried many things and nothing worked i use windows 7

I have tried some commands in command prompt like sfc /scannow but it didn't detect any corrupt files
i have also tried DISM and it did not benefit me

Comment: Got the same issue using IntelliJ 2023 2 build 232.8660.185

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem with all IntelliJ IDEA-based IDEs; like @welyss states, it's because the app starter `.exe` calls `CreateAppContainerProfile` is available only with Windows 8+, and IntelliJ officially bumped minimum requirements to Windows 10 in the meantime.

However, the IDEs are actually runnable, since they are just Java apps, and the `.exe` just calls a `.bat` that runs the JARs in JVM, so as long as you can run the matching JVM, you'll be good.

The way to handle this in practice is to run e.g. `rider.bat` from the install `bin` subdirectory (or any similar `.bat` file you have there in your particular IDE) instead of the e.g. `rider64.exe` that the main installer link provides. It worked for me perfectly (tested on Rider 2023.3.3 e.g.). No real need to upgrade anything *yet* (YMMV).

---

<sub>If you want to have a plug-and-play fix that requires no changes in the app paths etc. (e.g. for integration with other tools that require you to supply a correct IDE starter `.exe` path), you can ever use a simple `.bat` wrapper executable, like the one generated by the code below:</sub>

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  return system( strcat( argv[0], ".bat" ) );
}
```

<sub>, then just name the compiled exec e.g. `rider64.exe` and put it where the original app resides, copy the `rider.bat` to `rider64.exe.bat` there, and you're good to go; this works as a simple-but-effective workaround for virtually all cases when you need an `.exe` and you have a `.bat` (using the bat2exe etc. tools from 'net is usually a bad idea IMVHO, they are prone to different caveats).</sub>

Comment: For Android Studio, you should run studio.bat instead of studio64.exe (they are both in bin directory).

Answer (score 1):

same issue, and i found out Minimum supported client(windows) of CreateAppContainerProfile function is Windows 8 [desktop apps only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-createappcontainerprofile), and my case is win7 + IntelliJ 2023, same as you, guess IntelliJ 2023 call the function, maybe we have to upgrade os

Comment: System requirements: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/?section=windows

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77896308/17825391 on the internals. It's only the `.bat` runner that's incompatible ATM - as long as you run the startup `.bat` yourself, you'll be good.

Answer (score 1):

Launch studio.bat in the C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin